# Неправильный вывод информации о пользователе

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
     $post_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `user1`=$myrow2[id] OR `user2`='$id' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
     while ($run_post = mysql_fetch_array($post_query)) {
      $post_id = $run_post['id'];
      $post = $run_post['post'];
      $post_date = $run_post['date'];
      $post_time = $run_post['time'];
      $username = getuser($myrow['id'], 'username');
    $family = getuser($myrow['id'],'family');
      $post_avatar = getuser($myrow['id'],'avatar');

?>

<div class='box'>
  <?php echo "
<img src='/".$post_avatar."' width=50px border=0px>"?><?php echo "  $username $family "  ?>   |<font color='#4aaee7' size='2px' >  <?php echo $post_time; ?></font>
<br/>
```

выводит некорректно информацию аватарки, фамилии и имени. Помогите, в чем проблема?

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: а что выводит?, какие данные в переменных? Что возвращается по данному запросу из БД?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, нужно заменить:

```
$myrow['id']
```

на

```
$myrow[$id]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = **getuser**($myrow['id'], 'username');
$family = **getuser**($myrow['id'],'family');
  $post_avatar = **getuser**($myrow['id'],'avatar');
```

(выводит не корректно инофрмацию **аватарки и Фамилии и Имени**.ПОМОГИТЕ В ЧЕМ ПРОБЛЕМА?)

Посмотрите свою функцию getuser(); возможно там ошибка..

Comment: function getuser($id, $field){
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
  $run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  return $run[$field];
}

Вот моя функция с друзьями выводит все правильно, а с комментариями нет.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в верстке, врятли это касается Вашей проблемы, но исправьте всеравно

```
<div class='box'>
  <?php echo "<img src='/".$post_avatar."' style='border:0; width:50px;' alt='' />"?><?php echo $username." ".$family "; ?> |<span style="color:#4aaee7; font-size:8px;' > <?php echo $post_time; ?></span>
<br/>
```

Насчет ошибки, скажите, что у Вас выводит и что должно выводить

Comment: Извините то что так долго не мог ответить.Вот есть 2 юзера. У них например id1 и id2,так вот. Я захожу через id1 и пишу у себя.То выводит все мое: аватарка.имя.фамилия,а вот если пишу другому пользователю то выводит не мое все, а его.аватарка.имя.фамилия